# Combining starts_with with group_by in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I guess it might be a simple trick, but I do not know how to achieve it...

My dateset looks like:

```
Name, Score
A a,  20
A,    30
B b,   40
```

The output I expect is:

```
Name, Score
A,    50
B,    40
```

In one word, sum the scores that have names which start with the same word (before the space if there is one). I hope the example is self-explanatory. :)

PS: The faster the code runs, the better. The dataset is huge...

Comment: Pretty simple in base R `aggregate(Score ~ cbind(Name = sub(" .*", "", Name)), df, sum)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option would be `separate`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
separate(df1, Name, into=c("Name", "extra")) %>% 
       group_by(Name) %>%
       summarise(Score=sum(Score))
#     Name Score
#    (chr) (int)
#1     A    50
#2     B    40
```

Or `extract`

```
extract(df1, Name, into= "Name", "(\\S+).*") %>%
            group_by(Name) %>%
            summarise(Score = sum(Score))
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the tidyr library. It turned out to be very handy.

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df$newName <- str_extract(df$Name, '[[:alnum:]]+')
df %>% group_by(newName) %>% summarise(Score = sum(Score))

Source: local data frame [2 x 2]

  newName Score
    (chr) (int)
1       A    50
2       B    40
```

Note, you will want to make sure 'Name' is read as a character vector and not as factors. Use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in your read call, or use `as.character` to convert it.

If you want the full first 'string', you can also use this regex pattern:

```
df$newName <- str_extract(df$Name, '([^\\s]+)')
```

Answer (score 3):

`starts_with` is used in `select` and `rename` and are operations on the columnnames not on the values in the columns. By using `gsub` you can extract the first letter (or word) and then summarise. With:

```
sumdf <- mydf %>% 
  group_by(Name = gsub("[^A-Za-z0-9].*", "", Name)) %>% 
  summarise(sumScore = sum(Score))
```

you get:

```
> sumdf
   Name sumScore
1     A       50
2     B       40
```

Answer (score 3):

I used `substr` to extract the first letter and then `group_by`. I believe that dplyr `starts_with` is used to make a selection of whole columns based on their titles. This solution only works if the letter you want to select is always the first letter.

```
require(dplyr)
df<-data.frame(Name=c("A a,","A,","B b"),Score=c(20,30,40))

df$Name <- substr(df$Name,1,1)
df %>% group_by(Name) %>% summarise(sum_score=sum(Score))

Source: local data frame [2 x 2]

   Name sum_score
  (chr)     (dbl)
1     A        50
2     B        40
```

You could also create the substring column as a new column and group by that if you want to keep the original data as it is.